# Error en Php usando Cron en ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

Tengo echo un **script** en php y quiero que se ejecute cada minuto por ejemplo, y en el crontab lo tengo así:

`cd /var/www/html/RestApi/ /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/RestApi/prueba.php`

La cosa es que si lo ejecuto sin estar en el directorio `RestApi` me falla el `include` que tengo en mi php con este error:

> PHP Warning:  include_once(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/RestApi/prueba.php
>   on line 5 PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
>   './vendor/autoload.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/RestApi/prueba.php
>   on line 5 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Illuminate\Support\Collection' not found in
>   /var/www/html/RestApi/prueba.php:12 Stack trace:
>    {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/RestApi/prueba.php on line 12

me podéis ayudar?

Comment: Parece que tienes mal la ruta del `include`. Prueba a poner la ruta absoluta. Si no indicas la composición de tus carpetas y como lo tienes en tu PHP no podemos sugerirte nada más.

Comment: Perfecto, poniendo la ruta absoluta funciona, mis dieses :D

Comment: Me alegro. Puedes dejarlo así, o indicar cómo es la composición de carpetas, en caso de que quieras evitar la ruta absoluta. Aunque, tratándose de un cron, no hay problema al dejarlo con la ruta absoluta. Lo único es que si es un dominio alojado por un hosting y éste cambia el nombre del `home` por ejemplo, te va a fallar, pero eso es poco probable.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la línea exacta de cron? Es posible que te falte un simple punto y coma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe una constante predefinida llamada [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/constants.predefined#constant.dir) (disponible a partir de PHP 5.3) que te permite usar el directorio en el que está alojado un script para evitar el uso de "." en las rutas relativas o simplemente evitar usar rutas absolutas:

```
<?php
include_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Eso te permitirá incluir archivos independientemente del directorio de trabajo.

Por otro lado, parece que tu línea de `cron` está mal. Debes separar la instrucción `cd` de la ejecución del PHP con un punto y coma (`;`) o un `&&`:

```
min hora * * * usuario cd /var/www/html/RestApi/ && /usr/bin/php prueba.php
```

De esa manera primero se posicionará en el directorio de trabajo y luego se ejecutará el script (he omitido la ruta absoluta en la ejecución porque tras posicionarte correctamente no se requiere y te aseguras que se ha posicionado correctamente).

Hacerlo de esta manera te permitirá hacer portable tu script y cambiarlo de ruta sin tener que modificar el código para reflejar nuevas rutas absolutas cada vez que lo hagas.